# Unable to add all Firestore documents to a local variable in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I have a Firestore collection called `cattle-feed`. It has 7 documents. I am using a StreamBuilder to fetch these documents via a snapshot and add them to a list called `products`. `products` is initialized as an empty list.

**Issue faced:**

I am only able to add the first 4 documents of the `cattle-feed` collection to the list variable `products`.

**My Code:**

```
StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('cattle-feed').snapshots(),
         builder: (context, snapshot) {
           if(snapshot.hasData){
              products.clear();
                return ListView.builder(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index2){
                          // products.clear();
                          products.add(Map.from(snapshot.data!.docs[index2].data()));
```

What is wrong with my code which is letting me copy only 4 Firestore documents instead of all 7 and what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

try replace:

```
  products.add(Map.from(snapshot.data!.docs[index2].data()));
```

with:

```
  products.add(snapshot.data!.docs[index2].data() as Map<String, dynamic>);
```

Comment: It still adds only 4 items, not 7.